# Is it possible to package a Fyne app and cross-compile said app in one step?

Tags: go, cross-compiling, packaging, fyne

Fyne (https://developer.fyne.io/started/packaging) proposes a solution for packaging apps:

```
fyne package -os darwin -icon myapp.png
```

And another method for cross-compiling: https://developer.fyne.io/started/cross-compiling

I was wondering if there is a way to combine both, for instance to cross-compile *and* package a Fyne app on a Mac M1 for a Mac AMD.

Comment: I was making a mobile Fyne app a while ago. I found it pretty much impossible to cross-compile for iOS. There's some restrictions around the SDKs you'd need to compile for Apple products. See this portion of the `fyne-cross` project's `README.md`: https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne-cross#build-the-docker-image-for-osxdarwinapple-cross-compiling

Comment: It’s certainly not impossible, but you will need an Apple account to download the SDK - their license prohibits Fyne from packaging it with the tools.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use fyne-cross which automates most of the work using docker containers. https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne-cross

Answer (score 0):

According to the Fyne team:

You set GOOS and CC. suggested values at developer.fyne.io/started/cross-…

With the correct environment variables set it should compile the desired architecture (GOARCH would be needed as well in that instance). However you could also compile a binary and package it by passing “fyne package … -executable ” to use a pre-built file.

Comment: An obvious alternative is to build the executable for the desired target(s) and to package the app manually using, for instance the following template: https://github.com/codazoda/mac-app-shell

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way to package a Fyne app (manually):

1. Compile the executable for the choosen target, e.g.:

```
GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=1 go build
```

2. package the app manually using, for instance the following template:

`github.com/codazoda/mac-app-shell`